# React Native Lazy Collapsible Panel

Tags: typescript, react-native

### What is it?

React native <s>Accordion</s> Collapsible Panel.

You pass the *summary* (always shown bit) and the *detail* (sometimes hidden bit).

If the detail is passed as a function or promise (ie async function), it will be lazily called as it's expanded.

### (Questionable??) Design choices:

I allow all three types of *detail* into the same variable in the constructor, and there are two places I indulge in method existence checking to figure out what exactly I'm actually working with.

Is this a decent way to present this real-object vs lazy-init dynamic to coder using this component?

Am I type checking in a decent way?

Is there anything else?

### What it looks like:

Here are two collapsing panels rendered in a list:

[image]

### Code:

Usage:

```
// In some rendering function:

const mySummary: React.ReactElement = this.renderMySummary(obj);
const myDetail: () => Promise<React.ReactElement> = async () => this.renderMyDetailAsync(obj);
// ... or
// const myDetail: () => React.ReactElement = () => this.renderMyDetail(obj);
// const myDetail: React.ReactElement = this.renderMyDetail(obj);

return <CollapsingPanel summary={mySummary} detail={myDetail} />;
```

Class:

```
import React, { Component, ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, ViewStyle, TextStyle } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const styles: {
    summaryRow: ViewStyle,
    summary: ViewStyle,
    icon: TextStyle,
    parentHr: ViewStyle,
    child: ViewStyle,
} = {
    summaryRow: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    summary: {
        flex: 1
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    parentHr: {
        height: 1,
        width: '100%'
    },
    child: {
        padding: 16,
    },
};

type Props = {
    /** The part of this Component which is always shown */
    summary: ReactElement;
    /** The initially hidden part of this Component. Can be passed as a value, as a function or as asynchronous function.
     * The latter two will be evaluated only as the component is expanded
     */
    detail: (ReactElement) | (() => ReactElement) | (() => Promise<ReactElement>);
    /**
     * A marker property for triggering a re-render. Not neccesary when detail is changed.
     * But when using a invokable (lazy) detail, you may want this component to call the same function again because you expect different
     * results.
     */
    rerenderOnData?: {};
};

type State = {
    resolvedDetail: ReactElement;
    detailEvaluated: boolean;
    expanded: boolean;
};

export class CollapsingPanel extends Component<Props, State> {
    public state: State = {
        resolvedDetail: undefined,
        detailEvaluated: false,
        expanded: false
    };

    constructor(props:
        {
            summary: ReactElement,
            detail: (ReactElement) | (() => ReactElement) | (() => Promise<ReactElement>),
            rerenderOnData?: {}
        }
    ) {
        super(props);

        if (props.detail["call"] == null) {
            this.state.detailEvaluated = true;
            this.state.resolvedDetail = this.props.detail as ReactElement;
        }
    }

    public render(): ReactNode {
        const { summary } = this.props;
        const { resolvedDetail } = this.state;

        return <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.summaryRow} onPress={this.toggleExpand}>
                <View style={styles.summary}>{summary}</View>
                <Icon name={this.state.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.parentHr} />
            {
                this.state.expanded &&
                <View style={styles.child}>
                    {resolvedDetail}
                </View>
            }
        </View>;
    }

    public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Props): void {
        if (!this.state.detailEvaluated) {
            return;
        }

        if (prevProps.detail !== this.props.detail ||
            prevProps.rerenderOnData !== this.props.rerenderOnData) {
            if (this.state.expanded) {
                this.ensureResolved(true);
            } else {
                this.state.detailEvaluated = false;
                this.state.resolvedDetail = undefined;
            }
        }
    }

    private toggleExpand = () => {
        const expanding: boolean = !this.state.expanded;
        this.setState({ expanded: expanding });

        if (expanding) {
            this.ensureResolved();
        }
    }

    private ensureResolved(force: boolean = false): void {
        if (!force && this.state.detailEvaluated) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.props.detail["call"] == null) {
            this.setState({ detailEvaluated: true, resolvedDetail: this.props.detail as ReactElement });
        } else {
            const invoked: ReactElement | Promise<ReactElement> =
                (this.props.detail as (() => ReactElement | Promise<ReactElement>))();
            Promise.resolve(invoked).then(element => {
                this.setState({
                    detailEvaluated: true, resolvedDetail: element
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
    const invoked: ReactElement | Promise<ReactElement> =
                (this.props.detail as (() => ReactElement | Promise<ReactElement>))();
            Promise.resolve(invoked).then(element => {
                this.setState({
                    detailEvaluated: true, resolvedDetail: element
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```